# Rails/Active Admin/Formtastic - Dropdown cleared on fail validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

When I select a option from a dropdown on the new/edit view and submit the form to the create/update action, if another field within the same form fails the validation process when the view is returned the option selected from the dropdown has been emptied, this isn't a big problem in the new view but definitely in the edit view.

This is the code for the dropdown to be populated using formtastic collection method:

```
f.input :ethnic_category, :label => "Ethnic Origin", :collection => Hash[EthnicCat.all.map{|b| [b.ethnic_cat_name, b.id]}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks....